# page.EvaluateFunctionAsync() in Puppeteer Sharp is returning an empty array

Tags: c#, puppeteer-sharp

I'm scraping this website for information,using Puppeteer Sharp in C#:

https://www.grimtools.com/calc/Q2z07a9Z

If I open up dev tools in Chrome, go to the console and type in "dumpSkills()", I get a nice array of JSON as a response:

`(24) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]`

I want to get these objects in a variable in C#.

I can get this working in JS Puppeteer using the following:

```
const skills = await page.evaluate(() => {
  return dumpSkills();
});
```

Doing so seems to return the same array. Yay! However, I've been trying to get this working in Puppeteer Sharp. These are the things that I've tried:

```
var skills = await page.EvaluateFunctionAsync("dumpSkills()");

var skills = await page.EvaluateExpressionAsync(@"()=>{
    return dumpDevotion();
}");
```

I've also tried `WaitForExpressionAsync()` and `WaitForFunctionAsync()`, but can't seem to quite get it working. I seem to get empty '[]' or '{}' depending on which method I use.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created an small class model to map the values return by devotion:

```
class Devotion
{
  public string id { get; set; }
  public string name { get; set; }
  public string details { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can tell `EvaluateFunctionAsync` to return a list of devotions.

```
var devotions = await page.EvaluateFunctionAsync<List<Devotion>>("() => dumpDevotion()");
```

[image]

Comment: Heya. I tried it, had a syntax error due to the ';' in the string, removed that, but had the same effect - returns an empty array.

Comment: @WyreZ I improved the answer :)

Comment: Ty! Ok, so I tried what you said, but had the same issue which led me to believe that the issue wasn't Evaluating the Function.  I haven't narrowed down exactly what's causing the issue, but after removing some of the previous stages in my code and using your approach, it works as intended. So thank you!! Now to find what's actually causing the problem...